# Changing upper case & lower case letters

Tags: formatting

I just wrote 6 paragraphs of a report without really looking at the screen, and when I did, all of my upper case letters were lower case, and vice-versa. I had left the caps lock on. Is there a one-button solution to changing that? Highlite the whole page and hit "Sitch upper/lower case? Or do you always just have to start over?

Comment: I guess this is more a text editor related question than a TeX question, isn't it?

Comment: Not one but 4: `V6j~` (vim).

Comment: Almost every editor comes with this feature, emacs is my favorite to take care of such situations. If you are not familiar with emacs, and do not want to go through its steep learning curve, use either MS Word or Libre Office Writer (copy-paste, convert case, again copy-paste back) for the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

This is unrelated to TeX, if your (unspecified) editor can not do this, tools like tr can:

```
echo 'tHE WORDS ARE wrong!' | tr [:upper:][:lower:] [:lower:][:upper:]
```

produces

```
The words are WRONG!
```

Answer (score 1):

This it not really TeX related.

But I foudn [this](http://www.textfixer.com/tools/uppercase-lowercase-text.php) and [this](http://www.convertcase.net/) website I think both fit your purposes. Just googled `text uppercase tool`.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit - cracked it, should now ignore commands.**
**Edit 2 - now handles commands terminated by space, as well as those ending with `}`.

In notepad++ (which I heartily recommend for editing .tex) I think you  can do it using regex find&replace.  Just replace:

```
(\\[a-zA-Z0-9_,\{]*[\}\ ])|([a-z])|([A-Z])
```

with

```
($1)\U($2)\L($3)
```

ensuring that "match case" is selected (and probably "within selection").

This should ignore commands now.  If it still switches some, you may need to add more characters to the first set of brackets [character class] in the *find* regex.

If you've typed loads of text in with caps on, including commands, the regex is simpler - replace:

```
([a-z])|([A-Z])
```

with:

```
\U($1)\L($2)
```

Which will invert the case of all characters in the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can open your file with **vim** , select the text you want and press `~` on the keyboard while in normal mode. This will switch the case of all the letters.